# Initialize Python Custom Distribution

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, statistics, distribution

I am using a custom log gamma distribution in Scipy and I want to use it with a variety of predefined Scipy Distributions. My issue is that it seems Custom Distributions need to be a handled a bit different than predefined distributions. Specifically, it seems I need to initialize the custom distribution before it can be used. See below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gamma
from scipy.special import gamma as gamma_func
from scipy.special import erf, erfinv
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous
from scipy.stats import lognorm, norm

class custom_lgamma(rv_continuous):
    """ 
    pdf defined on page 227 in the book https://www.amazon.com/Loss-Distributions-Wiley-Probability-Statistics/dp/0471879290
    The parameters of this distribution are a and lambdax
    """
    
    dist_name = "Custom_Log_Gamma"
        
    def _pdf(self, x, a, lambdax):
        """ pdf of the log gamma function """
        return (lambdax**(a)*(np.log(x))**(a-1))/(x**(lambdax+1)*gamma_func(a))

    def _cdf(self, x, a, lambdax):
        """ cdf of the log gamma function """
        u = lambdax*np.log(x)
        return gamma.cdf(u, a=a)
    
    def _sf(self, x, a, v):
        """ survivial fuction of the log gamma function. This is 1 - CDF. """
        u = lambdax*np.log(x)
        return 1 - gamma.cdf(u, a=a)
    
    def _ppf(self,x, a, lambdax):
        """ inverse cdf of the log gamma function. This is required to conduct efficient random variable simulation. """
        u = gamma.ppf(x, a=a)
        return np.exp(u/lambdax)
    
    def _argcheck(self, a, lambdax):
        """ check that the fitted parameters fall within the required bounds """
        param1_test = a > 0
        param2_test = lambdax > 0
        return param1_test and param2_test

test_data2 = custom_lgamma().rvs(a=5,lambdax=3,size=1000)

lg = custom_lgamma()
lg.fit(test_data2,floc=0,fscale=1)

custom_lgamma().fit(test_data2,floc=0,fscale=1)
```

Both of these implementations work, however, I want to be able to use the custom distribution without having to initialize it, similar to how predefined distributions are used:

```
norm.fit(test_data2)
```

The predefined distribution does not require an initialization or a callable. If I try to use a custom distribution in this manner I get the result:

```
custom_lgamma.fit(test_data2,floc=0,fscale=1)

>>>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-9b87a6428141> in <module>
----> 1 custom_lgamma.fit(test_data2,floc=0,fscale=1)

TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'
```

Is there a way to define a custom scipy distribution so that it does not require initialization or a callable? My scipy is 1.5.2. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not initializing your distribution; it's just how SciPy's distribution infrastructure is built. You are confused between an instance of the `rv_continuous` class and the `rv_frozen` class.

When you call your distribution class (`custom_lgamma` in your case), SciPy generates documentation and code for the user interface which creates the distributions we see and use from `scipy.stats` (e.g. `norm`, `gamma`) (this is what happens when you do `custom_lgamma()`). This instance contains methods such as `pdf`, `cdf`, etc that are called **with the shape parameters** (just like other `scipy.stats` distributions).

Calling this instance again (e.g. `norm()`) will create a *frozen* distribution (an instance of the `rv_frozen` class) whose shape parameters cannot be changed (which is what would happen if you call your `custom_lgamma` instance again or do `custom_lgamma()()`). This instance has the `pdf` method that just accepts the quantile parameter.

Here is the convention that SciPy uses:

```py
class custom_lgamma_gen(rv_continuous):
    # implement your distribution methods here.
    ....

# this is the instance containing user interface of the distribution.
custom_lgamma = custom_lgamma_gen(name="custom_lgamma")


# now, you can call the fit method just like you would
# do with other scipy.stats distributions.
custom_lgamma.fit(test_data2,floc=0,fscale=1)


# to create a frozen distribution, do:
custom_lgamma_frozen = custom_lgamma()


# now you can call the methods without shape parameters
custom_lgamma_frozen.pdf(0.5)
```